# cakePHP one to one association help needed

Tags: relationship, one-to-one, model-associations, cakephp-2.x

So far this is the part of cakePHP that boggles my simple brain.

I have for this example 2 tables.
vw_penkits and vw_bushings

vw_penkits has a field vw_bushing_id

Here are the Models:

```
class VwPenKit extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'VwPenKit';
    var $useTable = 'vw_pen_kits';

    public $hasOne = 'VwBushing';
}

class VwBushing extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'VwBushing';
    var $useTable = 'vw_bushings';

    public $belongsTo = array (
        'PenKit' => array (
            'classname' => 'VwPenKit',
            'foreignKey => 'vw_bushing_id'
            )
        );
}
```

Here is the VwPenKitsController index()

```
public function index() {

    $this->loadModel('VwBushing');
    $bushings = $this->VwBushing->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('$bushings'));

    $this->set('penkits', $this->VwPenKit->find('all'));
}
```

Here is the code section for index.ctp

```
<td><?php echo $penkit['VwPenKit']['kit_name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $penkit['VwPenKit']['kit_description']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $penkit['VwBushing']['code']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $penkit['VwPenKit']['modified']; ?> </td>
```

Here is the error when rendered

Pen Kit Database
Version 0.1

Part No.        Kit Name    Description Bushing Modified    Actions
DK-PKCP8020     Bolt Action Pen (30 Cal)
Notice (8): Undefined index: VwBushing [APP/View/VwPenKits/index.ctp, line 46]  2015-04-07 11:00:00 View    Edit    Delete
Created by: Mike Marek

Contact information: mike@thewoodartiststudio.com.

©2015 The Wood Artist Studio - All Rights Reserved
also once I get this figured out I need an add.ctp and edit.ctp that create a selection list so that user can associate a pen kit to its bushing.

I don't have enough status yet to post images

Thanks in advance
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the issue and it basically was a Model problem. Once I had the relationship correct all works fine.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it could have to do with your recursive value in your find. If it is set to 0 then it will only find the first level. You need to set it to 1 or 2 depending how deep you want to find.

I would highly recommend making use of the ContainableBehaviour. It will make your life a whole lot easier.

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).